# converting matrix into cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 2d

I have a 2 d matrix like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   1
0   0   0   1   1   0
0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   1   0   1   0
0   0   1   0   1   1
0   0   1   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   1
0   0   1   1   1   0
0   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   0   0
0   1   0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   1   1   1
0   1   1   0   0   0
0   1   1   0   0   1
0   1   1   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   1   1
0   1   1   1   0   0
0   1   1   1   0   1
0   1   1   1   1   0
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   1   1
1   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   1
1   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   1
1   0   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1   1
1   0   1   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   1
1   0   1   1   1   0
1   0   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   1   0
1   1   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I want to convert this matrix into something like the following:

```
100000
100001
100010
```

and so on...

Comment: What is the relation between the Matrix and "100000 100001 100010". You want to convert the matrix into cell as the number of rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @Shai might be what you are looking for, but I read your question to ask about how to concatenate the rows of the matrix to form a vector.

It then depends on what type of format you want for your output, but here is one way to get a vector of numbers instead of the matrix.

```
>> A = eye(3)

A =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

Convert the matrix into string:

```
>> B = num2str(A)

B =

1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

Extract the `char`s that correspond to digits (and leave out the spaces):

```
>> C = B(:,1:3:end)

C =

100
010
001
```

Here you've got your values as strings which might be what you want (even if it is not really a vector). You could also convert this back to numbers, but then you will get an output of the following kind:

```
>> D = str2num(C)

D =

   100
    10
     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)

```
 c = mat2cell( x, ones(1, size(x,1)), size(x,2) );
```

Though, from your example, it seems like you are more interested in [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html):

```
 n = 6; % all binary numbers with n bits
 c = dec2bin( 0:(2^n - 1), n );
```